# How can i convert .txt to .flv？

Tags: flv, file-type

I have a .flv video and  want to copy it. l modified the suffix of the video. l opened this file using sublime and copy data. Then I created new .txt file, pasted data, saved it. Finally, I modified the new text file to .flv. It cannot work. I tried to make you understand my problem. Can somebody tell me the reason?

Comment: I guess that the encoding of the files is different.

Comment: What operating system do you use? You need to use a **hex editor** not a text editor.

Comment: FLV files are binary files that cannot be edited in a text editor. Why not just copy the file using your operating system facilities? (eg. CTRL+C the file in Windows Explorer, or use `cp` in a shell in Linux)